# Can't perform a React state update - useEffect issue - React Native

Tags: reactjs

Can someone help me, why react native throws unmount component error after login. Everything is loading after login without problem, just get the warning, even use the isSubscriber hack.
I'm using useReducer and AsyncStorage pckg for localstorage.

```
export function useAuth() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let isSubscribed = true;
    if (isSubscribed) {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('user').then((user) => {
        if (user) {
          dispatch(createAction('SET_USER', JSON.parse(user)));
        }
      });
    }
    return () => {
      isSubscribed = false;
    };
  }, []);
```

```
const { login } = useContext(AuthContext);
<Button
   onPress={async () => {
      await login(email, password);
   }}
/>
```

BR,

Comment: Seems like dispatch actions fires after the unmounting of the component. What is the component that uses this code?

Comment: is used through context api, i destruct the useAuth, and call login function on onPress.

Comment: What is the "isSubscriber" hack? Do you mean checking if `isSubscribed` is true ***within*** the AsyncStorage callback/chain to help gate further state updates after it's initiated?

Comment: No, it's something on useEffect level, so I can remove memory leaks with setting it to false in the destructor i.e return function.... at least that's how i found on net how to fix this issue...

Comment: `let isSubscribed = true;` lets the `AsyncStorage.getItem` chain start any time the component is still mounted (otherwise the effect would not run), and nothing is gating anything once the chain is started, so any state updates occurring later in the chain (after component unmounts) will still execute.